# infomap is an un-recognized package in my laptop

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have installed infomap on my Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

But when I want to use it in python program just like:

```
from infomap import infomap
```

I get this error:

```
No module named infomap
```

do I have to import any packages before it? what is wrong?

Comment: What is infomap exactly? The command you use it install basic build utilities, I don't think it installs infomap.

Comment: Have you tried in the command line to do 'pip install infomap'? Because to me it seems you install something to linux but never did the python module.

Answer (score 0):

infomap is a python [pip software package](https://pypi.org/project/infomap/). You need to install it via pip, which is a python package manager. Try `pip install infomap`. If it gives you an error about pip not being found, you need to install it with something like `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, but I think it's a part of the build-essential package you already installed.

Comment: my pip is broken while I upgrade it!! so I cannot use it!  this error:  https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240     so do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @ReihanehKouhi actually looks like a familiar issue I've come across. It may be related to running Python 2 code through Python 3 or the other way around. What version of Python do you have installed? There's also a pip for python2 and python3 (you can try 'sudo apt-get install python3-pip')

Comment: my python version is 2.7.12.   I try "sudo apt-get install python3-pip" now. How can I call it? just using pip install infomap?     this again causes to the same problem of:  cannot import name main.  If i use pip3 install infomap, it will cause to error:  upgrade your pip!     I also use pip3 install infomap --user.   not work again, the same error of:  upgrade your pip!

Comment: @ReihanehKouhi Is it just telling you there's a later version? Because that's OK, that doesn't mean it's not installing, just that there's a later version of pip3 available for download. Try running your program again - does it import the module properly?

Comment: no! this is the error while I want to install infomap:  Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-o3mrhgqp/infomap/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-fr4y_m2s-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-o3mrhgqp/infomap/

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help any further. You have a dependency issue possibly related to your python install, not really a code issue. I think it's beyond the scope of a programming question, more in the realm of [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and consideration.